# d3 collapsible hierarchy tree in Google Colab [Colaboratory]

Tags: d3.js, google-colaboratory

I am able to view a collapsible d3 tree in my browser on my desktop by following the instructions in [this](https://github.com/kyhau/d3-collapsible-tree-demo) post. In summary, these are the instructions:

1. Copy `collapsible_tree.html` and `input_graph_tree.json` both into the folder from where you execute python e.g. in `C:/Python37/`
2. Run python `python -m http.server 8080`
3. Go to URL: localhost:8080/collapsible_tree.html

I would like to replicate this on Google Colab, but am not sure if this is possible. I have moved the two files to `root` and have tried variants of `!sudo python -m http.server 8080` but nothing happens (i.e. code runs but with no outputs). Is there a way?